# Want to trim last (2) characters on a column of type text, is there a way to do this in the same column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I had searched for a solution and they all require creating another column, I want to know if there is a way to do it within the same column? I have DAX as well but just starting out on it so not as familiar with the abilities it has to offer.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do it exactly the same way using `Table.Transform` rather than `Table.AddColumns`. In the GUI, just use the Transform tab instead of the Add Column tab.

---

In the GUI, go to Transform > Extract > First Characters and pick some value, say, 2. That should output a step with the code:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step Name",
      {{"TextColumn", each Text.Start(_, 2), type text}})
```

This gives the first 2 characters but you want all but the last two. So replace `2` with `Text.Length(_)-2` in the formula line to get `Text.Start(_, Text.Length(_)-2)`.

If you prefer, `Text.RemoveRange(_, Text.Length(_)-2, 2)` should work too.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm quite new to M-code environment

Comment: A solution involving adding a column should work the same as a solution transforming a column in this case. Please see my edit.

Comment: I'll try it out!